# Cannot read property 'tickets' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am following a tutorial on Redux from this [book](http://www.pro-react.com/). Since that book is a little bit dated (2015) it uses `Flux` but on its website it has now provided an Appendix free for download that would implement Chapter 6 in [Redux](http://www.pro-react.com/materials/). There are two apps as demo apps. First one is the Fake Bank which I was able to follow and run it (with a little tweaking) and now the second the AirCheap app, I could not run. It give me this error `Cannot read property 'tickets' of null`. There are a lot of errors and cases like this in SO but I could not find that would suit mine. I am fairly new to React which is fine, but I have hard time with Redux (implementation-wise) and thus trying to get my hands dirty more on this demo supposedly.

The error comes from this line of **App.js**

```
let  ticketList = this.state.tickets.map((ticket)=>(
    <TicketItem key={ticket.id} ticket={ticket} />
));
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Select from 'react-select';
import AirportActionCreators from './actions/AirportActionCreators';
import TicketItem from './components/TicketItem';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import '../App.css';

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
  this.props.fetchAirports();
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
let originAndDestinationSelected = nextProps.origin && nextProps.destination;
let selectionHasChangedSinceLastUpdate = nextProps.origin !== this.props.origin ||
    nextProps.destination !== this.props.destination;
if (originAndDestinationSelected && selectionHasChangedSinceLastUpdate)
{
  this.props.fetchTickets(nextProps.origin, nextProps.destination);
 }
}

render() {
// Error here
let  ticketList = this.state.tickets.map((ticket)=>(
    <TicketItem key={ticket.id} ticket={ticket} />
));

return (
  <div>
    <header>
      <div className="header-brand">
        <img src="logo.png" height="35"/>
        <p>Check discount ticket prices and pay using your AirCheap points</p>
      </div>
      <div className="header-route">
        <Select
          name="origin"
          value={this.props.origin}
          options={this.props.airports}
          onChange={this.props.onChooseAirport.bind(this,'origin')}
        />
        <Select
          name="destination"
          value={this.props.destination}
          options={this.props.airports}
          onChange={this.props.onChooseAirport.bind(this,'destination')}
        />
      </div>
    </header>
    <div>
      {ticketList}
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

App.propTypes = {
 airports: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
 origin: PropTypes.string,
 destination: PropTypes.string,
 tickets: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
 fetchAirports: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 onChooseAirport: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 fetchTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
{
  airports: state.airports
   .map(airport => ({
    value: airport.code,
    label: `${airport.city} - ${airport.country} (${airport.code})`
  })
),
 origin: state.route.origin,
 destination: state.route.destination,
 tickets: state.tickets
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
{
 fetchAirports: () => dispatch(AirportActionCreators.fetchAirports()),
 onChooseAirport: (target, airport) => dispatch( 
  AirportActionCreators.chooseAirport(target, airport) ),
fetchTickets: (origin, destination) => dispatch(
  AirportActionCreators.fetchTickets(origin, destination))
});


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

It seems that tickets has no data at all but even if I do some checking like

```
if (this.state.tickets.length>0)
```

Or do like:

```
let ticketList = this.state.tickets && this.state.tickets.map((ticket)=>(
 <TicketItem key={ticket.id} ticket={ticket} />
));
```

I still get the same error.

I suspect also that it could be that `api` to fetch data needs to be run but there was no instruction of doing so from the book.

Comment: There are over 7200 existing posts found with a search for *cannot read property of null*. Not a single one of those posts was helpful? I find that pretty hard to believe, if you're actually trying to understand what was written instead of trying to find an exact match.

Comment: I did go through some of them but not all of them obviously.

Comment: @Edper I've been doing the same example but has not yet reached this tickets part in that book. I'm already having trouble mapping the state airports as props. Could you please provide me the github repo of this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not set any `tickets` as a `state`.

In `mapStateToProps` you are defining `tickets` as a `props`. because it's **mapping Redux state to current component props** so check it out:

```
let ticketList = this.props.tickets && this.props.tickets.map((ticket)=>(
 return (<TicketItem key={ticket.id} ticket={ticket} /> ) /* dont forget return */
));
```

Edit: and don't forget return `map()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check on this one.